# Prepayment of mortgage in summer

Tags: mortgage

In Veronesi's Fixed Income Securities book it is written:

> Summers are characterized by large prepayments, as this is the period
>   in which people move from one place to another for various reasons.

But why the fact of moving from one place to another will trigger prepayment?

Comment: Maybe he meant that people are paying off their mortgages because they sell the house.

Comment: @void_ptr Yes it seems like a good explanation for me

Answer (score 3):

"prepayments" in the mortgage world include when a mortgage is either refinanced or paid off when a house is sold. Since financially the effect is the same, there's no distinction made between "extra" payments and payoffs.